# Style based on default style MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I have default style for all `Label`

```xml
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter ...
</Style>
```

Then I have style with `x:Key` for `Label`

```xml
<Style x:Key="notForAll" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter ...
</Style>
```

So, if i do this

```xml
<Label Style="{StaticResource notForAll}"/>
```

This label will not include default label style, only `notForAll` style.

**How can I base `notForAll` style on `default` label style**? I can`t put default style into `BasedOn`

```xml
<Style x:Key="notForAll" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource ????????????}">
    <Setter ...
</Style>
```

I found **solution for WPF**

```xml
<Style x:Key="NamedStyle" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
    <Setter ...
</Style>
```

But it **doesn't work for MAUI**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Style inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml#style-inheritance) says:

> An implicit style can be derived from an explicit style, but an explicit style can't be derived from an implicit style.

I think that you have to do something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="commonLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter ...
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource commonLabelStyle}">
    <Setter ...
</Style>

<Style x:Key="notForAll" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource commonLabelStyle}">
    <Setter ...
</Style>
```